# How to count numbers in a list from a csv file filtering out words and commas

Tags: python, list, csv, python-3.x

So im fairly new to python and im looking to do a few things:

1. Display the number of numbers in the row
2. Display the average of the numbers in the row
3. Display the name of the row
4. No use of libraries such as import csv

the raw csv file has 3 rows

```
TTT TTTT, 21.72, 29.3, 20.08, 29.98, 29.85
DDDD, 57.51, 47.59
WWWW, 75.0, 82.43, 112.11, 89.93, 103.19, 80.6, 89.93, 103.19, 8
```

I have been at this for hours now and i simply can't get it my best attempt is the following

```
with open('test1.csv', newline='') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    print (content)
    for line in content:
        entry = line.split(',')
        entry = line.split()
        print (entry)
        nums = 0
        list1avg = 0
        list1=[]
        for c in entry:
            if is_number(c):
                print ("is num "+c)
                list1.append(c)
                nums+=1
            else:
                print(c)
        for i in list1:
            list1avg = list1avg +1
        print(list1avg)
        print(nums)
        print("The average is "+list1avg/nums)
    print("Total numbers in this row is " +nums)
```

i know its a mess but any help is appreciated.

Comment: `csv` is not an external library, it's part of the standard library. The way to do things in Python is to use the tools that are provided.

Comment: "No use of external libraries" How about regular expressions?

Comment: I cannot use libraries at all sorry i thought all library were external, how would i go about using regular expressions?

Comment: comma missing, meant to be treated as two separate entries

Comment: Just to clarify, can you use regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want, and is fairly readable:

```
with open('test1.csv', newline='') as f:
    for line in f:
        cols = line.split(',')
        numbers = [float(i) for i in cols[1:-1]]
        mean = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
        name = cols[0]
        print("The row contains %s" % ','.join(numbers))
        print("The average for %s is %2f\n" % (name, mean))
```

Let me know if that helps!

EDIT:

This is for the additional stuff you wanted to do. I've omitted the code that handles printing, as well as calculating standard deviation, since it's too early in the morning for me to remember math.

```
with open('test1.csv', newline='') as f:
    cols = {'count' : [], 'mean' : [], 'median' : [], 'minimum' : [], 'maximum' : [], 'std dev' : []}
    names = []
    for line in f:
        row = line.split(',')
        numbers = [float(i) for i in row[1:-1]]
        num_count = len(numbers)
        mean = sum(numbers) / num_count
        name = row[0]
        names.append(name)
        cols['count'].append(num_count)
        cols['mean'].append(mean)
        cols['minimum'].append(min(numbers))
        cols['maximum'].append(max(numbers))
```

To actually use `cols`, you can do something like:

```
for col in cols['count']:
    print(col)
```

Comment: cleanest solution in the thread but doesn't sum the numbers aswell as or1426 code did.

Comment: Is there any way i could output this into a table and display that table in pythons command line?

Comment: How do you mean? A table with lines and the sort?

Comment: In that case, it would be worth storing the values for each column, then saving them for calculation.

Comment: Also, your question doesn't say anything about summing the numbers, so I excluded that.

Comment: Sorry rob i was fooled by the fancy presentation of the other code, but yours does exactly what i asked, are you saying to save each value inside the for loop and then display outside the for loop, correct? But how do i get a neat looking table to display in python?

Comment: That will just take some effort with printing out the right characters. Or you can use one of the many libraries for such a task. If you're doing a lot of statistical stuff like this, I would very highly recommend something like NumPy or Pandas, since they can calculate most of those values for you.

Comment: Ah ok, ive got a basic table drawn up, one last thing how do i count the number of numbers in the row? not the average of the sum but the number of numbers if that makes sense?

Comment: I will update the code to get you started. Make sure you understand what it's doing.

Comment: Sorry about the hassle i figured it out btw, i know i must seem like an idiot: print (len(numbers)) - the number of numbers

Comment: That's alright, gotta learn somehow. I've added code that should help with printing and doing further calculation on the numbers. You can add as many columns to `cols` as you like.

Answer (score 0):

just to get the number of numbers and the row, you could do something like this

```
with open("csv_exmp.csv") as f:
    items = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]
    for item in items:
        numerbs_amount = sum(map(is_number, item))
        print numerbs_amount, " in row:", item[0]
```

if you want to count the average etc. just store the data in some variables outside of the for-loop

Comment: Slow loris for example has 2 words as a name and this will only print the first name. And this wont differentiate in say a list of 200 entries if only 50 of the entries are numbers it will still count 200 entries instead of only 50.

Comment: how will this count 200 entries? `is_number` should return `True` or `False` and summing this will count the exact amount of numbers

Comment: is_number comes with which version of Python?

Comment: is_number is a function i wrote myself
    def is_number(num):
        try:
            float(num)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

Comment: if `is_number` returns True or False `sum([True, False, False, True, True])` will return `3`

Comment: It does too, thanks for your help i dont fully understand everything i write yet hahaha

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Roseman said the right way to do this is to use the `csv` library (which is not external but part of the python standard libraries). As you seem (for whatever reason) to be interested in not using the csv library you should note that you can split a string based on a substring rather than just a char:

```
with open('test1.csv', newline='') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip() # remove the trailing `\n`
        tokens = line.split(', ') # note comma and space
        name = tokens[0]
        numbers = list(map(float, tokens[1:]))
        average = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
        print(numbers)
        print("Name={}, number={}, average={}".format(name, len(numbers), average))
```

Comment: wow, perfect answer i cant up vote you because i literally made this account a few seconds ago and their is reputation restrictions but you have helped me immensely